# Inserting 'sign-up' date into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a sign up form and I am trying to record the date the form was filled out, into MySQL table. All of the information that I am requesting within the form is being recorded, except for the date. Would anyone be able to help me out with this task?

Here is a snippet of my PHP code of where I think the problem resides. I am also using PHPmyadmin for my database; if that is relevant.

Here is the link to the page  www.3elementsreview.com/sign-up

```
    $value = $_POST['First'];
    $value2 = $_POST['Last'];
    $value3 = $_POST['City'];
    $value4 = $_POST['State'];
    $value5 = $_POST['Country'];
    $value6 = $_POST['Email'];
    $value7 = $_POST['Y-m-d H:i:s'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO members (First, Last, City, State, Country, Email, Date) VALUES     ('$_POST[First]','$_POST[Last]','$_POST[City]','$_POST[State]','$_POST[Country]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Date]')";
```

Comment: Give us the structure of your table (datatypes of fields)

Comment: The fields in the table are id, First, Last, City, State, Country, email, date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is dangerous and allows sql injection attacks.

First off mysql_* library is depreciated.

Second if you are going to use mysql_* functions, use mysql_real_escape string on ALL your POST fields.

Thirdly this will solve your issue:

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['First']);
$value2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Last']);
$value3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['City']);
$value4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['State']);
$value5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Country']);
$value6 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO members (First, Last, City, State, Country, Email, Date) VALUES     ('$value','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6',NOW())";
```

in mysql, the function NOW() is used to return the current date/time.

Comment: Thank you. Protection against MySQL injections is next on my "to do list". One thing though, how could I change the date format? Is there a way to display a 12hour clock?

Comment: you should store the dates 1 way, mysql keeps it in its own fashion. Where you want to format it is either in the select query, or on outpu of the PHP code. Here is a function to use in sql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

Unless your parameter is called `Y-m-d%20H:i:s=____`, you should probably be collecting a `$_POST['date']` variable or something, then converting it into a date after assigning it to a variable.

```
$value7 = $_POST['date'];
$value7 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value7);
```